Running location service in background without requesting
Location Service is running in the background and repeatedly sends data. In my Flutter app, there is no requesting location, but I am using Firebase Messaging, MobileAds, and google_sign_in packages. When I review the logs, the location is using Google Service. How do I trace this? It causes my app's main thread to overload and eventually get an issue. Please, how to fix this?
This is the log of location:
11-24 00:37:31.429: gps provider +registration 10135/com.google.android.gms[fused_location_provider]/514E0E97 -> Request[@+5s0ms HIGH_ACCURACY, hiddenFromAppOps, WorkSource{10198 com.tps.juniorx}]
    11-24 00:37:31.430: gps provider request = ProviderRequest[@+5s0ms, HIGH_ACCURACY, WorkSource{10198 com.tps.juniorx}]
    11-24 00:37:31.431: passive provider +registration 10135/com.google.android.gms[fused_location_provider]/DC20AC7D -> Request[PASSIVE, minUpdateInterval=0, hiddenFromAppOps, WorkSource{10135 com.google.android.gms}]
    11-24 00:37:35.152: gps provider -registration 10135/com.google.android.gms[fused_location_provider]/514E0E97
    11-24 00:37:35.152: gps provider request = ProviderRequest[OFF]
    11-24 00:37:35.154: passive provider -registration 10135/com.google.android.gms[fused_location_provider]/DC20AC7D
    11-24 00:37:36.920: gps provider +registration 10135/com.google.android.gms[fused_location_provider]/514E0E97 -> Request[@+5s0ms HIGH_ACCURACY, hiddenFromAppOps, WorkSource{10198 com.tps.juniorx}]
    11-24 00:37:36.924: gps provider request = ProviderRequest[@+5s0ms, HIGH_ACCURACY, WorkSource{10198 com.tps.juniorx}]
    11-24 00:37:36.929: passive provider +registration 10135/com.google.android.gms[fused_location_provider]/DC20AC7D -> Request[PASSIVE,

